# How to make a MenuStrip with a custom check button?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, calculator

How to make a `MenuStrip` in Visual Studio 2012 that shows a custom check button like this?

[image]

Comment: You can start by looking here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404318.aspx

Comment: That other question *is* a duplicate, although it has a very poor answer. Anyone who comes along this question with a few spare minutes is strongly encouraged to post a good *complete* answer to the duplicate question.

Comment: As for you, tjnapster555, I strongly recommend skipping the ugly `MenuStrip` control. Instead, add the [`MainMenu` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mainmenu.aspx) to your toolbox (it is not there by default). It has [a property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menuitem.radiocheck.aspx) to do exactly what you want, and it matches the system theme. You'll never get `MenuStrip` to do that.

Comment: i was looking for a tutorial of MainMenu i didn't find any information can give me a link that show how to make MainMenu control @CodyGray